# Introducing the folowing to avoid undefined TypeError in react causes a weird bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, function, undefined

I am working in React and came across an undefined type error. So to do this, I did the following, which was introduce the `|| {}` in the return statement. Basically it solves the issue in which it doesnt throw a type error anymore, however, there is now a bug in which it renders an empty state, even though there is data. I think the data just loaded slow. Is there any way

Comment: you have an issue here, try changing if condition amountByCurrency.find(acct => acct.id === currentAccountId) || {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `{}` doesn't make sense where it is.

```
return amountByCurrency.find(acct => acct.id === currentAccountId || {}).assets;
```

The callback is:

```
acct => acct.id === currentAccountId || {}
```

So, with the first element of the array, either `acct.id === currentAccountId` is fulfilled, and the callback returns true, or it falls back to `{}`, and objects are truthy, so the callback returns - and the first element of the array is the resulting "found" item.

If no items exist in the array, an error will be thrown, because there's nothing to iterate over. The empty object in the callback doesn't do anything other than break the `.find` logic.

You should instead do something like

```
filterCurrencyBalances() {
    const { amountByCurrency, amountByAsset, currentAccountId } = this.props;
    if (currentAccountId) {
        const foundAcct = amountByCurrency.find(acct => acct.id === currentAccountId);
        return foundAcct ? foundAcct.assets : 0; // replace 0 with the desired default balance for no account
    }
    return amountByAsset;
}
```